# Standard datset of Animals with a mixture of popular animals

Tags: data-request

I am developing an image classifier that classifies vehicles and animals. For the testing purpose i need a medium size dataset of animals. Where can i find a standard datset of animals which include almost all popular variety of animals like tiger, lion, dog,bird etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sample size is pretty small, depending on the way you are using the material, I would be tempted to use google searches then utilise free pictures from the searches you find.

If you write a R script with RSelenium/Rvest and do searches like "dog picture free", etc. and loop through the popular names of animals that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[Flickr has an API,](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) and in particular the [.getPhotos endpoint](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.galleries.getPhotos.html), that allows you to get Photos from a specific group.

> **flickr.galleries.getPhotos**
>
> Return the list of photos for a gallery